# A CarPlay template using Siri to let the user choose between several action?

Tags: ios, messaging, siri, sirikit, carplay

I'm developing a CarPlay interface to a messaging application but couldn't find how the root CPTemplate, a grid template with button in my case, could activate SiriKit to let the user choose between several actions like we could see in WhatsApp running on CarPlay for example :

[image]

There is CPVoiceControlTemplate that seems to do the job but it is only allowed for navigation app category and not messaging and VoIP.
Actually my app could activate Siri to compose a message to a selected contact represented by a CPMessageListItem in a CPListTemplate but I couldn't find how to code a CPGridTemplate that activate Siri...

Comment: I think Apple decided that there is no need for this as usually there is a button in the car to activate Siri (eg : long press on on car phone physical  button)